# Celery Beat doesn't work with Django

Tags: python, django, celery, celerybeat

I configured Celery to work with Django but whenever I start Celery Beat it never gets past this stage

```
> LocalTime -> 2018-05-20 16:55:50
Configuration ->
    . broker -> redis://localhost:6379//
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%DEBUG
    . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)
```

No tasks scheduled.
I'm using Celery 4.1.0